# Trying to access a oracle db but a trigger preventing me to connect

Tags: oracle, database-trigger

I am trying to connect to this oracle db but it has a trigger in there that is preventing me from connecting to that db. I tried to connect from apex also but its giving me the error.

Is there any other way i can remove this trigger from the DB?

[image: Error when trying to connect to the db]

Comment: Connect as sysdba user and see if it allows you to login.

Comment: No i cannot....

Comment: One of the SYSDBA users needs to recompile the custom ADMIN.AFER_LOGON trigger as it has become invalid. If SYSDBA can not log on to fix this, then you need to revert to a backup of the database from before the trigger went invalid.